# Cant write from root user into sqlite when sticky bit is set

Tags: linux, sqlite, ubuntu

I have a sqlite data base in the folder with a `sticky bit` in permissions. The folder is onwed by `root`. The db file is owned by no root user and has full permissions:

```
ibse@ibse-VirtualBox:/var/internal$ ll
total 32
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root  4096 кві 16 12:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 кві 16 10:47 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ibse ibse 21504 кві 16 12:00 mydb.dat*
```

When I try to INSERT into the database from the `root` user, the database rejects with `attempt to write a readonly database`:

```
ibse@ibse-VirtualBox:/var/internal$ sudo sqlite3 mydb.dat

SQLite version 3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54
Enter ".help" for usage hints.

sqlite> INSERT INTO DATA (sent) VALUES (1);
Error: attempt to write a readonly database
sqlite>
```

But when I remove the sticky bit from the folder containing the database file, I can INSERT into one:

```
ibse@ibse-VirtualBox:/var/internal$ sudo chmod -t .
ibse@ibse-VirtualBox:/var/internal$ sudo sqlite3 mydb.dat

SQLite version 3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54
Enter ".help" for usage hints.

sqlite> INSERT INTO DATA (sent) VALUES (1);
sqlite>
```

Why it so? If I right understand the `sticky bit` concept, the `root` user can manage all the files in the folder, even if sticky is set

Comment: I can't find the source right now - but if memory serves me right, both the DB file AND the enclosing folder need to have write permissions for the user who attempts to change the DB. 
So maybe include a screenshot from the permissions on internal/ ?

Comment: @BAerts I gave information about permissions on `internal/` at the very beginning of my post. I apologize if this was not fully understood. `internal/` has `drwxrwxrwt 2 root root  4096 кві 16 12:00` permissions

Comment: my bad - you are right ... what happens if you do the same test not as root (i.e. cancel the sudo) ? what happens if you make sure the owner of both the folder and the file are either root, or ibse ( chown ) ? I ask because of this article https://www.pantz.org/software/sqlite/unabletoopendbsqliteerror.html - while https://www.linuxnix.com/sticky-bit-set-linux/ says only the owner of the directory could remove temp DB files